# mysql myisam bulk import from dump file is very slow

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php to backup mysql database.

99% of this database is MyIsam table.

```
exec("mysqldump -u root -ppassword dbname | mysql -u root --password=password safe_dbname");
```

In this way, it is fast to back up but importing is very slow in php.

Is there any solution?

Comment: proper indexing and not using MyISAM would be a start, but you should include more details about your schema in the question.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.